# How can I set multiple optimize parameters in C++ source code

Tags: c++, attributes, auto-vectorization

I'm currently getting familiar with C++ code optimization via auto vectorization. Since we work in a large repository I like to activate optimization for specific functions instead of setting them globally.

How can I achieve this?

I use GCC 5.4.0 as well as accompanying ARM GCC cross compilers in the same version. I tried to set multiple arguments with the `__attribute__((optimize("flags")))` statement but it did not work. I know that I can export these functions into a separate source file and use compiler pragmas, but it would be easier to attach this directly to the function in question.

I tried different combinations of

```
__attribute__((optimize("tree-vectorize", "fast-math")))
```

or

```
__attribute__((optimize("tree-vectorize")))
__attribute__((optimize("fast-math")))
```

but none seemed to work.

Here is the full function:

```c
__attribute__((optimize("tree-vectorize", "fast-math"))) //Enable auto-vectorization
inline void
vecSqrt(const float32_t* const input, float32_t* const res, const size_t N)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        res[i] = sqrtf(input[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope somebody can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: If you try with compiler flags (e.g. `-ftree-vectorize` and `-ffast-math`) do you see any difference then? Perhaps those specific optimizations doesn't do anything specific with that function?

Comment: If I set both flags globally, together with `-fopt-info-vec` the compiler tells me that it was able to vectorize the loop. So yeah, I definitely works.